# Are there any major outstanding recalls of bicycle parts?

Tags: safety

Sometimes bike companies don't get things right.

Are there any major recalls people should know about? Where can people find information on recalls?

There is one answer which has places to find information on recalls (for a given country). Other answers could be by part.

(Moderators: I'd like this to be community wiki)

Answer (score 3):

## Places to Find Information on Recalls and Safety Issues (in alphabetic order)

### Canada

- https://recalls-rappels.canada.ca/en (English)
- https://recalls-rappels.canada.ca/fr (French)

### New Zealand

- https://www.recalls.govt.nz/

### United States of America

- The [US Consumer Product Safety Commission](https://www.cspc.gov) is the organization responsible for recalls and safety issues in the USA.
- [Recalls.gov](https://www.recalls.gov/)
- To report safety issues, [SaferProducts.gov](https://www.saferproducts.gov/)
- A convenient listing, [Consumer Affairs](https://www.consumeraffairs.com/bicycle-recalls)

Answer (score 2):

## Brakes

- The Avid Single Digit 7's have been [recalled](https://www.cpsc.gov/Recalls/2018/SRAM-Recalls-Bicycle-Brakes): CPSC Recall Number 18-002.

> Description: This recall involves the Avid SD7 bicycle mechanical rim brake. There is a date code stamped on the back of the brake arm with the date format DDMMYY representing the day, month and year of manufacture. The brakes were sold separately by SRAM and were also installed as original equipment on ElliptiGO model 11R elliptical cycles.
>
> Remedy: Consumers should immediately stop using the recalled brakes and contact SRAM to receive free replacement brakes and installation instructions.
>
> Incidents/Injuries: SRAM has received five reports of loose or detached rivets. No injuries have been reported.
>
> Sold At: Specialty bike stores nationwide and online at www.jenson.com and www.REI.com from June 2014 to May 2017 for about $40, and installed as original equipment on ElliptiGO model 11R elliptical cycles from October 2014 to May 2017 for about $3,500.
>
> Importer(s): SRAM LLC, of Chicago, Ill.
>   Manufactured In: Taiwan
>   Units: About 7,000

Answer (score 2):

## Quick Release

http://bpsa.org/quick-release-recall/

> Certain front-wheel quick-release cam levers that are improperly adjusted or left open while riding can come in contact with the front-wheel disc brake rotor, also potentially causing the front wheel to come to a sudden stop or separate from the bicycle, posing a risk of injury to the rider.

Only applies if your bike has a disk brake, and a QR lever that could interfere with the disk in any open or closed position.

This could affect bikes from the 90s through to about 2015.

Comment: With a standard QR on a disk bike it is quite common practice to place the QR in such a way that the lever is on the right side of the fork. You'll avoid touching the hot disk inadvertently when opening the QR if you have a flat. (It can also be done at the rear but it's trickier.)

Comment: @Carel of course - that's good common sense.  But the recall exists because of the possibility the QR lever is on the same side as the rotor, AND that the lever might interfere with the rotor at any time.    This recall does not apply to the rear QR, but same situation exists there - The rear lever often ends up on the disk brake side and may interfere with the rear rotor.

Answer (score 2):

### Shimano Recalls Cranksets for Bicycles Due to Crash Hazard

Name of Product:
11-Speed Bonded Hollowtech II Road Cranksets

Hazard:
The recalled bonded crank parts can separate and break, posing a crash hazard to consumers.

Recall Date:
September 21, 2023

Units: About 680,000 (in addition, 80,000 were sold in Canada)

References:
https://www.cpsc.gov/Recalls/2023/Shimano-Recalls-Cranksets-for-Bicycles-Due-to-Crash-Hazard
and
https://recalls-rappels.canada.ca/en/alert-recall/shimano-bonded-crankset (currently generates a 404 error, but will hopefully get fixed)

Answer (score 1):

## Manufacturers

This is a non-exhaustive list.

- **Brompton** https://www.brompton.com/About-Us/BB-Checker-Consumer
- **GT** http://www.gtbicycles.com/usa_en/recalls/
- **Haro** https://www.harobikes.com/safety-recall
- **Schwinn International** http://www.schwinnbikes.com/int/support/recalls/
- **Schwinn USA** http://www.schwinnbikes.com/usa/support/recalls/
- **Trek** https://www.trekbikes.com/us/en_US/company/legal_policies/safety_recalls/

Answer (score 1):

### Shimano PRO Vibe Bicycle Stem recalled due to injury hazard

Product
Shimano PRO Vibe Bicycle Stem
Issue
Consumer products - Injury hazard

What to do:

Immediately stop using bicycles with PRO Vibe alloy handlebar stems and take them to an authorized retailer to determine if the stem is subject to the recall.

Affected products:

This recall involves Shimano PRO Vibe bicycle stems. The stems can be identified by its black coloured alloy with a prominent silver “V” branding on the faceplate of the stem. The stem has forward facing mounting bolts.

Models with bolt heads at the front of the faceplate are not subject to this recall.

Issue:

The stems may form cracks and break over time causing the rider to lose control and fall, posing a risk of injury.

Reference:
https://recalls-rappels.canada.ca/en/alert-recall/shimano-pro-vibe-bicycle-stem-recalled-due-injury-hazard

Answer (score 1):

### Shimano recalls Lazer Bicycle Helmets

Starting date:    October 23, 2018
Posting date:    October 23, 2018
Type of communication:    Consumer Product Recall
Subcategory:      Sports/Fitness
Source of recall:      Health Canada
Issue:      Product Safety
Audience:      General Public
Identification number:      RA-68074

Affected products
Lazer Bicycle Helmets
Product description

This recall involves the following Lazer bicycle helmets:

```
Blade, Size extra small and small
Elle, Size small
Jade, Size small
Magma, Size small
```

The helmets have ID Code LZB-08. The size and ID code can be found on the inside of the helmet.

Hazard identified:

The recalled helmets do not meet the CPSC standard for the "Dynamic Roll Off" test. The helmet may come off on impact posing a head injury to the user.

Time period sold:

The recalled helmets were sold from January 2015 to April 2018.

What you should do:

Consumers should immediately stop using the helmet and return the helmet to Shimano North America for a free replacement (with free shipping).

Reference:
https://recalls-rappels.canada.ca/en/alert-recall/shimano-north-america-recalls-lazer-bicycle-helmets